# div fit its content with transform resizing

Tags: html, css

I want main div to fit its content and not expanded as you see

I want to fit the height and the red color not expanded.

[image]

```html
<div id="main" style="margin-top:10px;cursor: pointer; width: 280px; border-radius: 7px;overflow: hidden; position: relative; background-color:#F00; border:3px solid #000; direction: rtl;">
  <div style="width: 280px; ">
    <div class="rtl" style=" width: 1400px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transform-origin: right top 0px; transform: matrix(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0);">
      <section class=" ">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
              <div >
                <div ><h2>Hello</h2></div>
                <div><p>You are welcome </p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
              <div class="">
              <img src="images/hello.jpg">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: max-width: 100%?=)

Comment: I want to fit height and color red not expaneded

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. Manipulate the div by setting the width of the div to fit-content. `width: fit-content;`
2. Manipulate the image by setting the image size to 100% and set display to block. `width: 100%; display: block`

Comment: I want to fit height and color red not expaneded , no problem with width

Comment: @khalidseleem okay I finally figured it out... there's something wrong with you're transforms... Do you understand the transform property and cubic beziers? or are you still learning them? I only ask because cubic beziers are pretty complex and require an advanced understanding of math and the transform property. So is it necessary that you use the bezier function can't you do whatever you want to do using the other more simpler transform properties?... I myself don't understand them much either so I usually just use the other easier properties.